# Prevent React Native packager from running each time a build is executed in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

The react native packager is executed each time I build my project (and there is no packager running). I know that this is somewhat intended behavior because the script responsible for starting the packager is part of the React's project build phase.

The thing is we're not always developing on react-native component. Most of the time we are actually fine developing with the offline bundles that are embedded in the app. Therefore we prefer that the react native packager doesn't start on each build.

This is the script that is part of React's project build phase:

```
if [ -z "${RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER+xxx}" ] ; then
  if nc -w 5 -z localhost 8081 ; then
    if ! curl -s "http://localhost:8081/status" | grep -q "packager-status:running" ; then
      echo "Port 8081 already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly"
      exit 2
    fi
  else
    open "$SRCROOT/../packager/launchPackager.command" || echo "Can't start packager automatically"
  fi
fi
```

What I've tried so far:

- Create a user defined setting `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER` with value `1` under Build Settings of our project. This doesn't work and only seems to have effect when added to the 'React' project itself. Not really useful since this configuration will be cleared if someone reinstalls their node_modules.
- Add a environment variable `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER` with value `1` to Arguments of the Run phase of the build scheme within our project.

Also, a system-global variable RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER is not something to consider as this would automatically affect all projects.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am trying to figure out same thing. Did you get this solved?

Answer (score -1):

I just deleted "$SRCROOT/../packager/launchPackager.command" to avoid launching packagers automatically. You can either do it manually or add it a script in your project.